Error en linea que ya no existe
Estoy haciendo un proyecto con flet y Python, estaba probando diferentes métodos para posicionar un contenedor con una propiedad que  es top=100. Al ver que no me funcionaba la eliminé; ahora cada vez que ejecuto el código Python me recuerda que tengo un error en esa línea que eliminé, cabe aclarar que antes sí se ejecutaba el código.
from flet import *
import flet  as ft

def formregistro(event):

     contenedor = Container(
        width= 275,
        height=275,
        content= Column([texto,nombre,apellido,correo,Row([dia,mes,año])]),
        bgcolor=colors.BLACK12,
       alignment=alignment.center
    )
    page.add(contenedor)

Error:
>  top=100

SyntaxError: invalid syntax. Perhaps you forgot a comma?


Luego de intentar por varias horas como el error se soluciono elimiando la carpeta __pycache__ esta guarda archisvos pyc (python compilado), la cual estaba almacenando en memoria el codigo que ya no existica
